# Android Emulator Tips and Tricks

Tags: android, android-emulator

What is your Emulator feature that you could not work without?

Which unknown great shortcut, console command or startup option is there that you discovered and you think has to be also known by all other Android devs?

Share your Emulator wisdom with us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

F6 - start track ball emulation

When working with high resolution screen, one can reduce the size of the emulator to make it fit better on PC screen: AVD Manager - Start - check "Scale display to real size" and set Screen size to a suitable value (6 works for me)

Answer (score 20):

Not exactly an emulator feature but related.

When using Eclipse for Android development, the debug certificate that is automatically created only lasts 1 year. When it expires, it's a pain to have to delete all your development .apk files, because the new certificate doesn't match so you can't upgrade them in all your AVDs. You have to get another development MAP-API key as well. The published recommendation is to simply delete the debug.keystore file and Eclipse (ADT really) will create a new one for you, again with a 1 year expiration. But you can create your own debug certificate in debug.keystore with whatever expiration you want. Do this in the .android folder under your HOME directory:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000

ADT sets the first and last name on the certificate as "Android Debug", the organizational unit as "Android" and the two-letter country code as "US". You can leave the organization, city, and state values as "Unknown".

Comment: Wow that is really helpfull and good to know. I'm not developing for Android. Have to check how long my debug certificates will last.

Answer (score 16):

You can enable/disable the Emulator Network with: F8

Great for testing service interruptions while your app is connected to some web based service.
It allows very fast disabling just at the moment a download or a webservice started.

Comment: That doesn't work always for me. Don't know why. The better way in that cases to turn on airplane mode :)

Comment: Yeah but airplaine mode is not instantanious, if the F8 thing is working it is the fastest way to do something like,: Oh I wonder what happens if this request is started, and then the connection is dropped.

Comment: It worked for me on Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 16):

You can rotate it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: I always rotate it by pressing 7 on the keypad (with numlock disabled)

Comment: The full list of keypad/keyboard shortcuts is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling

Answer (score 14):

You can try your hands on a bunch of tricks using keyboard key and taken from the Android official documentation. See the below image.

[image: Emulator tricks and tips]

Answer (score 11):

[You can get the Android Market running in the emulator.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/)

Answer (score 8):

Demonstrate an android app from a USB stick

Assuming you want to show a friend/client your app and their machine has no Android SDK, Eclipse or even an uptodate  JRE, you can put all you need on a USB drive without affecting your development environment.

Make an 'androiddem' folder on the stick, copy a minimal sdk (don't need the docs or samples) with the platforms you need and a Java runtime to their own folders.

Open a DOS box from the root of the USB drive and set a local environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the root of the drive. (This env variable is a bit of misnomer if you use Eclipse as it doesn't need it and picks up the SDL location from the general Android preferences). It does control where the AVDs get created though, so once you've set it to h:\ (say), you can drop down to to the tools directory on the stick and create AVDs in the normal way - they will end up in .android on the stick.

If you copy the .apks that you want (make sure they were signed with a release key) to the stick, then from another DOS box(with the ANDROID_SDK_HOME set as before you can use the adb commands to install the apks to the AVDs you made.

All you have to do then is take the stick to the target machine, open a DOS box again, set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME, prepend the JRE to the path and run the emulator nominating the target AVD.

You can simplify the process by creating batch files on the stick to set env variables and paths.

Comment: Nice I have to try to create a Stick that I can leave with a client that enables them to start an emulator. They could get the newest APK from my Webspace via the Emulator Browser.

Comment: This is a good idea, which I have used at a few place I work.  I use this as a more permanent solution, so I can install Android on non-Dev's machines.  I basically un-zip that same thing you have on the USB, set the ENV variables permanently.  I then created a simple script to launch the emulator, and install an APK file.  Good Tip!

Answer (score 8):

Keep the emulator open while developing to avoid the boot time.

(Source: Pragmatic Programmer's Hello Android book - Ha, I just read this yesterday.)

Comment: Yes basic tip but maybe the most time consuming error. Closing the emulator after testing an app will make you loose two minutes each time you start your app.

Comment: @Janusz - Yep, in fact, my first mistake was to keep closing the emulator each time I wanted to close the test app. My mistake. I learned the hard way.

Answer (score 8):

You can use DDMS to create screenshots from applications running on hardware. Just hit Ctrl-S from within the DDMS program. Great for creating screenshots for the Android Market, especially if your application runs poorly on the emulator.

I'd been capturing screenshots from the emulator and trimming them with Image Magick until I had this pointed out to me by a colleague at work.

[image: DDMS screenshot menu]

Comment: I learned this trick yesterday! I still create mockus via Sketch, I'm having problems in running the emulator on high res screens. This same feature exists even in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

Using DDMS to debug a service which has no Activity.

Assuming you've written a service in its own apk which to be used by another application, then it's not possible to set break points in the service app's code and have them trigger when the other app runs and invokes the service.

If, however, you go to the DDMS perspective, find the service's thread and highlight it, then click the bug icon in the DDMS, breakpoints are triggered.

This answers one of my own (unanswered) questions.

Answer (score 3):

Use ADB commands to optimize your work.
Very useful examples:

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.test.IntentName`  - simulate an intent

`adb shell date -s 19860407.115033` - change date/time (to my birthday ;)

`adb shell dumpsys alarm` - print registered alarms

Comment: Here is another important ADB command. "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED". It restarts your emulator. Handy if you are currently manually turning ON/OFF your phone for testing certain feature. The power button on the emulator doesn't work.

It is a pain to connect the ADB if you've never done it before but then I found this restart thing to be immensely useful.

Answer (score 2):

1) Reset adb every time the console has adb errors.

[image]

2) Use Launch options wisely:

2.1) If you have problem emulator "not responding" every time it starts, restart emulator with "wipe out user data". It will clear all apps installed before and make emulator fresh.

2.2) Checking "Launch from snapshot" will save time when starting emulator. It reads from a snapshot (if there is any).

2.3) Checking "Save to snapshot" will save a snapshot to run emulator immediately next time. Uncheck it if you want to close the emulator faster.

[image]

3) Backup "sdcard.img" if you intend to change its size. I used to lose data when I try to change its size.

4) Download and install [offline Android SDK](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html) if you have Internet connection problem on you computer.

5) [Install Android Market on emulator](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html).