# Testing Android apps in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

Is there any ways to test free Android applications (available from Google Play) using Android emulator?

This is useful if I want to test apps that uses latest APIs that my Android device do not support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263339/installing-android-market-app-on-emulator

Comment: Nice but Google play only comes with Device and any other ways that let you use it is illegal.

Comment: OK, but this makes the life of an Android developer hard?! Unethical activity from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just download the free apps directly from Google Play in the emulator. See https://apkudo.com/?p=510 for more details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any ways to test free Android applications (available from Google Play) using Android emulator?

Only if the author of those apps distributes them by direct download off their Web site, or by some other marketplace that is licensed such that you can install on an emulator.

> OK, but this makes the life of an Android developer hard?

Not especially IMHO, but you are welcome to your opinion.

> Unethical activity from Google.

Again, you are welcome to your opinion. IMHO, it is not unethical for Google to only license the Play Store to device manufacturers -- it *is* unethical to copy, distribute, and download it separately. Similarly, IMHO, it is not unethical for app developers to elect to solely distribute their apps through the Play Store -- it *is* unethical to copy, distribute, and download those apps separately.

Comment: Copying and distributing (when license does not allow it) is not just unethical, it is a crime and I am not searching a way to commit a crime. Technically it is not not impossible (for Google) to allow the emulator to download the encrypted (uncopyable and undistributable) format for testing, that is what I mean. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I myself found a reliable ethical and legal solution, which is really offered by Google itself.

You can install Android OS in your computer and test any free or purchased apps.

More details:

http://code.google.com/p/live-android/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=MgcJrvc2OYU