# Installing Flash Player on an Android Emulator

Tags: android, installation, emulation

I want to know the process(detailed please) of installing flash player on an android emulator. I need to do this to test an app and currently I don't have any physical device.

Things that i have already tried:
 1. i have checked out all the stack overflow links regarding this topic.
 2. i already know adobe has stopped flash for android. So links of google play store with flash player are all dead.
 3. i have tried installing it from a third party such as http://d-h.st/x4v but this link is a pain to open from the browser inside the emulator.

So please help of any sort is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through this: 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263339/installing-android-market-app-on-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the Android Emulator only comes with a select few applications installed, you can install others as long as you have access to the basic download file APK file. If you want to develop an application on your emulator that interacts with the Adobe Flash Player, there is a way to work around the limitations without installing the Android Market.

**Instructions**

**1** Download and install the Android emulator SDK on your Eclipse installation.

**2**  Download the APK file of the Adobe Flash player and save it to the "yourSDK/tools/" directory in your SDK installation. Replace "yourSDK" with the name of your SDK root directory.

**3** Run "adb install yourSDK/tools/flash.apk" in the shell in the SDK. Replace "yourSDK" with the name of your SDK root directory and "flash.apk" with the exact name of the Flash APK file.

Read more: How to Get a Flash Package on an Android Emulator | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_12172392_flash-package-android-emulator.html#ixzz2MM3xgmjX

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest archive from [Adobe's OFFICIAL page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html). You can do that from device. If the URL is too unwieldy, just [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com) it.

I've set this one up a while ago as it has come up more than once:
http://tinyurl.com/flash4ics It downloads the very last (truly the last one!) Flash player from Adobe.